# Uninterrupted attention span

Tags: attention

Wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attention_span) reports that attention can be sustained in adults for a few hours, but I remember studying that attention can be effectively held  only for a few seconds, after which the brain takes a short rest.
Can you give some details on this aspect of attention?